# Cannot load new View with navigation Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am new to IOS development, I'm trying to load a new view programatically. I have a root view. When the application start, the root view loads correctly. From the root view, When I press a button, I want to load a new view.

The custom class for the new view is : `PlaceDetailsController`

My code is:

```
 PlaceDetailsController *x = [[PlaceDetailsController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlaceDetailsController" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:x animated:YES];
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
2013-11-15 17:29:06.164 Info.mu.final[1806:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/noor/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/7FD5D7FC-38DE-448F-84F1-17879202DBA7/Info.mu.final.app> (loaded)' with name 'PlaceDetailsController''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x211b012 0x19cce7e 0x211adeb 0x1134ef9 0xff97e7 0xff9dc8 0xff9ff8 0xffa232 0xffa4da 0x10118e5 0x10119cb 0x1011c76 0x1011d71 0x101289b 0x1012e93 0x1012a88 0x2a05 0xaa3ca 0xa7c22 0x11e385a 0x11e299b 0x11e40df 0x11e6d2d 0x11e6cac 0x11dea28 0xf4b972 0xf4be53 0xf29d4a 0xf1b698 0x283bdf9 0x283bad0 0x2090bf5 0x2090962 0x20c1bb6 0x20c0f44 0x20c0e1b 0x283a7e3 0x283a668 0xf18ffc 0x226d 0x2195)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

The selected View is the View I want to load:
[image]

Any suggestion??

Comment: Do you have a xib PlaceDetailsController?

Comment: I'm using Storyboard, the Custom Class for the view I want to load is PlaceDetailsController

Comment: Ok. initWithNib wasn't working because of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling you're using Storyboarding, right?

To push a view with storyboarding enabled use the following code.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewIdentifier"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You need to make sure that you set the StoryboardID in the Storyboard (It's in the identity inspector (the third button in on the right once you've clicked your view controller)).

EDIT: If you are pushing a view from a Navigation Controller;

You need to set up a Segue (a lot easier than it sounds!). In your storyboard, Ctrl+Click on your view controller and drag it to your other view controller and choose 'Push', you need to give this Push Segue and Identifier too, this can be done in the Attributes inspector (make sure you've clicked the Push segue object!). Then in your code where you want the push to happen use the following:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

Comment: This one is working, but then do I need to add the item on the navigation bar to return to the previous view manually?

Comment: @user1774937 I've updated my answer :) Welcome to iOS Developement!

Comment: Thanks its working, but can you tell me why with the nibfilename it is not working, from samples I've seen, It should have worked? Isn't?

Comment: Sure, so because you're using Storyboards you need to do all of your through Storyboard calls. You can still use NIBs but you'll need to make them manually and call them - it's just a change in how iOS has developed recently.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to check that you set your customView to PlaceDetailsController in the xib/storyboard file. (go on the xib/storyboard file, click on the view, go to identity inspector on the right panel and be sure to see PlaceDetailsController in the custom class textfild at the top).

If that's correct, this error usually occurs when you rename some files outside XCode. To solve it you can just remove the files from your project (Right Click - Delete (be sure to only Remove Reference) and re-import them in your project.

Everything should be ok after that.